# How to scroll to invalid form field in angular

Tags: angularjs, forms, validation

I have a form with a lot of fields, some of them are required.

How can I use $anchorScroll

```
$location.hash("<errorFieldID>");
$anchorScroll();
```

to scroll to an invalid field?

I mean how can I know the id of the invalid field since :

1. the invalid fields only get an extra class , `ng-invalid-required`,
   so how can I get the id?
2. what happens when more than one field is invalid? where
       $anchorScroll will first scroll?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this out

1. `var error = $scope.formName.$error;
   angular.forEach( error.required, function(i, error){
   console.log(i.$invalid);
   if(i.$invalid == true && error == 0) {
   $('.ng-invalid').focus();
   }`
2. For the second one, what I have seen is that when there are multiple fields that get the class ng-invalid, it usually scrolls to the first one from the top.

.focus() usually does the trick. If you really want to use anchorscroll(), you can do so in the 'if' condition
Hope that helps.